# Iterating through twos list of lists in python

Tags: python, list

I am new to python programming and am having a hard time iterating through two lists of lists. My two lists are formatted like this:

```
L = [['cat', '1', '5'], ['cat', '7', '15'],['cat', '17', '20']]
A = [['coordOne', '1', '3'],['coordTwo', '8', '9'],['coordThree', '11', '13'],['coordFour', '18', '21']]
```

The two numbers in each list are start and end coordinates and I want to see if there is any overlap between the start and end coordinates when comparing both lists and then save the information into a new list. My desired list after the program runs would output:

```
newList:[['cat', 'coordOne'],['cat', 'coordTwo', 'coordThree'], ['cat', 'coordFour']]
```

my code so far is

```
    newList = []

    for i in range(len(L)):
        for j in range (len(A)):
            if i[1] >= j[1] and i[1] <= j[2] or i[2] >= j[1] and i[2] <= j[2] or i[1] <= j[1] and i[2] >= j[2] and j[2] >= i[2] or i[1] <= j[1] and i[2] >= j[2]:
                newList.append(L[i][0], A[j][0])


    print (newList)
```

I am receiving an error that 'int' object is not callable.

Comment: yeah i definitely meant, i[1] >= j[1] and i[1] <= j[2]

Comment: What do you expect ```i``` and ```j``` to be?  what does ```range``` return?  What happens with ```for i in range(6): print i```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparisons must be against ints, note `'2' < '12' == False`
You can change your complicated condition to test just the boundary conditions:

```
if int(i[1]) <= int(j[2]) and int(j[1]) <= int(i[2]):
```

or

```
if max(int(i[1]), int(j[1])) <= min(int(i[2]), int(j[2])):
```

These should be sufficient to determine if the ranges overlap.

I'm not suggesting this but this can be done with a comprehension if you accept a slightly different output:

```
>>> [(l, [a for a, a_start, a_end in A
...       if int(l_start) <= int(a_end) and int(a_start) <= int(l_end)])
...  for l, l_start, l_end in L]
[('cat', ['coordOne']),
 ('cat', ['coordTwo', 'coordThree']),
 ('cat', ['coordFour'])]
```

BTW the anticipated output for the OP algorithm is:

```
[['cat', 'coordOne'], ['cat', 'coordTwo'], ['cat', 'coordThree'], ['cat', 'coordFour']]
```

Which you could do with the comprehension too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "zip" function.

```
L = [['cat', '1', '5'], ['cat', '7', '15'],['cat', '17', '20']]
A = [['coordOne', '1', '3'],['coordTwo', '8', '9'],['coordThree', '11', '13'],['coordFour', '18', '21']]
newList = []

for (i,j) in zip(L, A):
    if i[1] >= j[1] and i[1] <= j[2] or i[2] >= j[1] and i[2] <= j[2] or i[1] <= j[1] and i[2] >= j[2] and j[2] >= i[2] or i[1] <= j[1] and i[2] >= j[2]:
        newList.append( (i[0], j[0]) )
```

Comment: This doesn't compare every element in L with every element in A, you are only checking L[0] with A[0] and L[1] with A[1], etc. (A[4] never gets compared).

Answer (score 1):

I get a different error to you: `IndexError: list index out of range`. This happens because of this test:

```
if [i][1] >= [j][1]
```

`[i]` is a list containing only `i`, which you then try to access the non-existent index 1 of (it only has one element, which is at index 0). You also have things that are just `i[1]` and `j[1]`, which will break with "`int` object is not subscriptable". You seem to mean:

```
if L[i][j] >= A[j][1]
```

Fixing all of these gives another error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    newList.append(L[i][0], A[j][0])
TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

Which you can fix by adding an extra set of brackets around that call (to append the *tuple* of `L[i][0]` and `A[j][0]`). This gives the type of output you expect:

```
[('cat', 'coordOne'), ('cat', 'coordThree'), ('cat', 'coordFour'), ('cat', 'coordOne'), ('cat', 'coordOne'), ('cat', 'coordFour')]
```

---

But there is a better way. First, iterating like this:

```
for i in range(len(L)):
```

is almost always an anti-pattern. You only ever use `i` and `j` to index the two lists; just do:

```
for l in L:
```

(but choose better variable names - it is common to have the list named as a plural, like `things` and do `for thing in things:`).

You have two nested loops to consider every element of `L` against every element of `A`. This is called a *cartesian product*, and the idiomatic way to do this is to use [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html):

```
import itertools as it

for l, a in it.product(L, A):
    if l[1] >= a[1] ... :
```

You might also want to consider using a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) so that you can give names to the things in each list, so you can test things like `if l.start >= a.start:`. This will make it much easier to reason about exactly what your code is doing, so that you can get your condition right.

Answer (score 0):

`i` and `j` are `int`s. use `L[i][...]` and `A[j][...]` in the condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(L)):
    for j in range (len(A)):
```

`i` and `j` here are both of type `int`, if you want them to be elements in `L` and `A`, use:

```
for i in L:
    for j in A:
```

Accordingly, change:

```
newList.append(L[i][0], A[j][0])
```

to:

```
newList.append([i[0], j[0]])
```

The code runs now, however the result is not expected, which would need more work.